# Parsing numbers safely and locale-sensitively

Tags: java, parsing, guava, apache-commons, apache-commons-lang

Java's `NumberFormat` is 1) non thread-safe (which can be worked around with a `ThreadLocal`); 2) [inconvenient to use correctly](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-numberformat/index.html) for the simplest use case when I know whether the string should contain int, long, or double, and want an API like:

```
int parseInt(String str, Locale locale) throws ParseException; 
int parseInt(String str, int defaultValue, Locale locale);
long parseLong(String str, Locale locale) throws ParseException;
long parseLong(String str, long defaultValue, Locale locale);
double parseDouble(String str, Locale locale) throws ParseException;
double parseDouble(String str, double defaultValue, Locale locale);
```

where the exception is thrown when the string isn't completely parsed. Obviously, such a wrapper is easy to write, but I couldn't find one in Guava or Apache Commons Lang. Did I just miss it? Or is there another more-or-less standard solution for this?

Comment: What's your issue with `Integer.parseInt` and brethren?

Comment: I guess it doesn't support varying number formats?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik They are locale-independent, so don't use the correct decimal separator, etc.

Comment: True, I forgot that you can get into a mess even with an `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option I've found is [Apache Commons Validator](http://commons.apache.org/validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/AbstractNumberValidator.html) (still non-thread-safe).