# Validating decimal numbers in a locale-sensitive way in Java

Tags: java, validation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parsing numbers safely and locale-sensitively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591810/parsing-numbers-safely-and-locale-sensitively)

How can I validate strings containing decimal numbers in a locale-sensitive way? NumberFormat.parse allows too much, and Double.parseDouble works only for English locale. Here is what I tried:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.GERMAN);

    NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.getDefault());
    Number parsed = numberFormat.parse("4,5.6dfhf");
    System.out.println("parsed = " + parsed); // prints 4.5 instead of throwing ParseException

    double v = Double.parseDouble("3,3"); // throws NumberFormatException, although correct
}
```

Comment: Should it throw an exception, if your locale is German, and the input is `3.3` instead of `3,3`?

Comment: `Number parsed = numberFormat.parse("4.5.6dfhf");` works too and produces `456`... Eurgh...

Comment: jlordo: at least it should accept correct numbers...

Comment: assylias: yes, that is what I mean by it allows too much... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regards of the

```
Number parsed = numberFormat.parse("4,5.6dfhf");
```

problem, you could possibly use **NumberFormat.parse(String source, ParsePosition pos)** and check if the position where it stopped parsing was indeed the last position of the string.

Also, on the 4.5.6 problem, you can try to set grouping off by **setGroupingUsed(boolean newValue)** as I think it's an issue produced by the '.' character being the grouping character on the locale.

It should be something like

```
NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.getDefault());
numberFormat.setGroupingUsed(false);
ParsePosition pos;
String nString = "4,5.6dfhf";

Number parsed = numberFormat.parse(nString, pos);
if (pos.getIndex() == nString.length()) // pos is set AFTER the last parsed position
   System.out.println("parsed = " + parsed);
else
   // Wrong
```

Comment: But that still would accept nonsense input like "4.5.6".

Comment: Actually the if(nString.length()  == pos.getIndex()) condition (without substracting one from length) seems to be the right condition

Comment: Andreas_D: I guess that dots are simply ignored, just like commas are ignored for English locale

Comment: If you found my answer useful, it would be cool to get it marked as correct! =)

Comment: Manuel Miranda: I guess both answers are correct, but anyway this seems to be more generic, so I'll accept this :)

Comment: Thank you!, and yes, both of them are useful

Comment: It seems that the GroupingUsed propery has effect only on the output formatting, but not on parsing

Answer (score 1):

From your comment above, you can use:

```
String input = "3,3"; // or whatever you want
boolean isValid = input.matches("^\\d+([.,]\\d+)?$");
double value = Double.parseDouble(input.replaceAll(",", "."));
```

If the separator can be something else besides the comma, just add it in the square brackets:

```
double value = Double.parseDouble(input.replaceAll("[,]", "."));
```

Comment: The problem is that it is not guaranteed that the locale is German. It could be anything. You think that this would work for any locale?

Comment: As long as the separator is a dot or a comma, it will work. I don't know of a locale, where the separator is something else.

Comment: How about spaces? `1 000 000` is probably valid in some locales. Trying to redevelop a locale-dependent parser sounds like a dangerous game...

Comment: This depends on how strict you want to be. If `1 000 000` is valid, is this `1 00 0000` or more than one space also?

Comment: @jlordo Exactly - it brings many border cases and it is very difficult to get it right.

Comment: IMHO a number in input can only be a sequence of digits optionally followed by a separator and another sequence of digits. Presenting (pretty printing) numbers is a completely different thing.